# launch external url from app and after it launch application from browser

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2

I want in ionic application, client press a button and

**launch browser and go to payment page with url**

and after payment is down (success or failed) bank redirect client to callback page , and I want in callback page, client press a button and

**launch application and go to order page**

I use `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser` for launching external url like this :

```
window.open('http://www.nraboy.com/contact', '_self')
```

but I dont know how to launch application from browser(deep linking) in ionic 2 (android platform)

Comment: If you're using window.open you aren't using InAppBrowser... cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url,target,options)... You also need to add event listeners for 'loadstart', 'loadstop','loaderror','exit' ... Then in the callbacks, target the event.url and check it for redirect to proper site.

Comment: I follow this tutorial : https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/07/launch-external-urls-ionicframework/

Comment: check the cordova official site - your tutorial doesn't seem legitimate to me: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/

Comment: I use this in a production app btw, I have working code using the official documented process.  It works.  window.open is vanilla.  cordova is accessed through the cordova reference.  If you don't start your call with cordova *dot* something, you are not using cordova, unless you're doing some "hacky" stuff, which isn't necessary.

Comment: thanks for useful response, how to lunch ionic 2 application from browser ?

Comment: Actually, look at the docs... it's not really that hacky, it's listed right at the top.  You can use window.open with: window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open; .... have you done that?  It might be all you need ... I haven't ever done it, I just use a var inAppref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open, but it looks like as long as you override it as per the docs it should work.  Assign a handler, and check the url...